How to switch to a dark background in iTerm2?
I've just installed iTerm2 on a Macos Sonoma system and I can't figure out how to use a theme with dark background in it. In the settings I select the Dark theme, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the main window, which remains light:

Any idea how to fix that?

Are you talking about the preferences window in your screen shot, or a shell window?

@Marc: It's from iTerm2: Settings-> Appearance

That wasn't my question.  I use Terminal.app myself, so I was asking whether you expected the preferences window to be themed darkly, and it wasn't, or a shell window, and it wasn't.

@Marc I care only about the shell window (outside of Settings on the screenshot)

If you went to your settings in iTerm2 and choose Profiles, and you selected the default profile. From there, you can choose the popup menu towards the right named "Color Presets" and selected the Dark Background option. IS that what you are looking for?

@ErniePC12: Yes, thank you very much! I'm still not sure what changing the Theme in "Appearance" does. IIRC, the background used to be dark by default, but now it's light, which is odd. BTW, feel free to add your solution as the answer so I can accept it.

In your screenshot, the Appearance tab allows you to select the theme, which affects how the areas outside the main terminal view are drawn. This is inline with the macOS's appearance light/dark mode.
If you select Profiles, you can create terminal profiles with different characteristics. Under the Colors tab, you can select some predefined  presets, like the Dark Background option I selected below. (My macOS appearance is set to Dark mode by default)
You can visit the online gallery or search online for iTerm2 Color Themes to find and import. You can also create your own theme by adjusting the different color options on the screen.

This information comes mostly from iTerm2's Online Documentation
